# Grok Pattern causing _grokparsefailure[0]

Tags: logstash, grok

I'm having trouble with a grok parse of syslog message.  The debugger shows no issues.  Is there a way to log grok to see why it's failing?

Input: `<37>May 22 23:02:53 myfirewall sshd: SSHD_LOGIN_FAILED: Login failed for user 'testthis' from host '10.0.0.1'`

Pattern: `SSHD_LOGIN_FAILED .*%{MONTH} %{MONTHDAY} %{TIME} %{WORD:host} %{WORD:daemon}: %{WORD:eventtype}: Login failed for user '%{USER:user}' from host '%{IP:ipaddress}'`

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: try starting logstash with --debug, I think it tells you stuff about grok filters

Comment: Works fine with Logstash 1.4.2. Are you sure Logstash is loading your pattern file? What does your grok filter look like in full? As @markus says, starting Logstash with `--debug` will probably give you hints.

Comment: So again, banging my head on the table...

Comment: Pattern is:
`%{MONTH}  %{MONTHDAY} %{TIME} %{DATA:sysloghostname} %{DATA:severity} .*\: %{DATA:event}\;.*rhost=%{IP:srcip}.*user=%{USERNAME:username}\\.*`

Data is:
`<85>Jun  3 18:16:20 systemname notice sshd[29058]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=59.63.192.199  user=root\n`

In debugger, no issues, and it's in my patterns file....

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tip.

What I found was that there are multiple locations that the pattern files exist on my test box for some reason.  The correct file didn't have my patterns in it.